# Adding the command \text{} to the TeXstudio autocompletion list

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

TeXstudio suggests  `\texttt{}` and `\textwidth` as completions for `\text`. It does not suggest `\text{}`. I believe that `\text{}` is part of the amsmath package, and amsmath.cwl is checked in preferences/completion. How can I get `\text{}` as one possible completion to `\text`?

Comment: Did you notice that there are tabs (most used, all, ...). Maybe you have to change the tab.

Comment: `\text` shows up in the completer for me with just the "typical" set. Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Have you loaded package `amsmath` or `mathtools`? If the document consist of several files, have you set the root document?

Comment: the root document is identified correctly.  The \usepacakge{amsmath} command appears in an included file

Comment: I half resolved the problem: \text{ appears as a completion when I pick the option for "all" completions but does not appear when I pick the option for "typical" completions. Is there a way to change TEXstudio's view of what is Typical?